# CSS / Java script dropdown menu horizontal not vertical

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

so i'm using a CSS menu I found online, forgot where, but like it. I implemented a drop down from a vertical drop down menu, the thing is.. it's horizontal instead.

Sorry for the long CSS below, the main parts are after all the FontAwesome tags.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
body {
  background-image: url("retro.png");
}
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 8px;
  float: left;
}
figure img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
figure figcaption {
  border-right: 2px dotted blue;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted blue;
  border-left: 2px dotted blue;
  border-top: none;
  text-align: center;
}
figure span figcaption {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-right: 2px dotted green;
  border-left: 2px dotted green;
  border-top: 2px dotted green;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.alvin {
  font-size: 13px;
}
#content {
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: #BDBDBD;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: both;
}
#banner {
  background: white;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background-image: url("retro2.jpg");
}
.icon-glass:before {
  content: "\f000";
}
.icon-music:before {
  content: "\f001";
}
.icon-search:before {
  content: "\f002";
}
.icon-envelope:before {
  content: "\f003";
}
.icon-heart:before {
  content: "\f004";
}
.icon-star:before {
  content: "\f005";
}
.icon-star-empty:before {
  content: "\f006";
}
.icon-user:before {
  content: "\f007";
}
.icon-film:before {
  content: "\f008";
}
.icon-th-large:before {
  content: "\f009";
}
.icon-th:before {
  content: "\f00a";
}
.icon-th-list:before {
  content: "\f00b";
}
.icon-ok:before {
  content: "\f00c";
}
.icon-remove:before {
  content: "\f00d";
}
.icon-zoom-in:before {
  content: "\f00e";
}
.icon-zoom-out:before {
  content: "\f010";
}
.icon-off:before {
  content: "\f011";
}
.icon-signal:before {
  content: "\f012";
}
.icon-cog:before {
  content: "\f013";
}
.icon-trash:before {
  content: "\f014";
}
.icon-home:before {
  content: "\f015";
}
.icon-file:before {
  content: "\f016";
}
.icon-time:before {
  content: "\f017";
}
.icon-road:before {
  content: "\f018";
}
.icon-download-alt:before {
  content: "\f019";
}
.icon-download:before {
  content: "\f01a";
}
.icon-upload:before {
  content: "\f01b";
}
.icon-inbox:before {
  content: "\f01c";
}
.icon-play-circle:before {
  content: "\f01d";
}
.icon-repeat:before {
  content: "\f01e";
}
/* \f020 doesn't work in Safari. all shifted one down */

.icon-refresh:before {
  content: "\f021";
}
.icon-list-alt:before {
  content: "\f022";
}
.icon-lock:before {
  content: "\f023";
}
.icon-flag:before {
  content: "\f024";
}
.icon-headphones:before {
  content: "\f025";
}
.icon-volume-off:before {
  content: "\f026";
}
.icon-volume-down:before {
  content: "\f027";
}
.icon-volume-up:before {
  content: "\f028";
}
.icon-qrcode:before {
  content: "\f029";
}
.icon-barcode:before {
  content: "\f02a";
}
.icon-tag:before {
  content: "\f02b";
}
.icon-tags:before {
  content: "\f02c";
}
.icon-book:before {
  content: "\f02d";
}
.icon-bookmark:before {
  content: "\f02e";
}
.icon-print:before {
  content: "\f02f";
}
.icon-camera:before {
  content: "\f030";
}
.icon-font:before {
  content: "\f031";
}
.icon-bold:before {
  content: "\f032";
}
.icon-italic:before {
  content: "\f033";
}
.icon-text-height:before {
  content: "\f034";
}
.icon-text-width:before {
  content: "\f035";
}
.icon-align-left:before {
  content: "\f036";
}
.icon-align-center:before {
  content: "\f037";
}
.icon-align-right:before {
  content: "\f038";
}
.icon-align-justify:before {
  content: "\f039";
}
.icon-list:before {
  content: "\f03a";
}
.icon-indent-left:before {
  content: "\f03b";
}
.icon-indent-right:before {
  content: "\f03c";
}
.icon-facetime-video:before {
  content: "\f03d";
}
.icon-picture:before {
  content: "\f03e";
}
.icon-pencil:before {
  content: "\f040";
}
.icon-info:before {
  content: "\f05a"
}
.icon-map-marker:before {
  content: "\f041";
}
.icon-adjust:before {
  content: "\f042";
}
.envelope-o:before {
  content: "\f003";
}
.icon-tint:before {
  content: "\f043";
}
.icon-edit:before {
  content: "\f044";
}
.icon-share:before {
  content: "\f045";
}
.icon-check:before {
  content: "\f046";
}
.icon-move:before {
  content: "\f047";
}
.icon-step-backward:before {
  content: "\f048";
}
.icon-fast-backward:before {
  content: "\f049";
}
.icon-backward:before {
  content: "\f04a";
}
.icon-play:before {
  content: "\f04b";
}
.icon-pause:before {
  content: "\f04c";
}
.icon-stop:before {
  content: "\f04d";
}
.icon-forward:before {
  content: "\f04e";
}
.icon-fast-forward:before {
  content: "\f050";
}
.icon-step-forward:before {
  content: "\f051";
}
.icon-eject:before {
  content: "\f052";
}
.icon-chevron-left:before {
  content: "\f053";
}
.icon-chevron-right:before {
  content: "\f054";
}
.icon-plus-sign:before {
  content: "\f055";
}
.icon-minus-sign:before {
  content: "\f056";
}
.icon-remove-sign:before {
  content: "\f057";
}
.icon-ok-sign:before {
  content: "\f058";
}
.icon-question-sign:before {
  content: "\f059";
}
.icon-info-sign:before {
  content: "\f05a";
}
.icon-screenshot:before {
  content: "\f05b";
}
.icon-remove-circle:before {
  content: "\f05c";
}
.icon-ok-circle:before {
  content: "\f05d";
}
.icon-ban-circle:before {
  content: "\f05e";
}
.icon-arrow-left:before {
  content: "\f060";
}
.icon-arrow-right:before {
  content: "\f061";
}
.icon-arrow-up:before {
  content: "\f062";
}
.icon-arrow-down:before {
  content: "\f063";
}
.icon-share-alt:before {
  content: "\f064";
}
.icon-resize-full:before {
  content: "\f065";
}
.icon-resize-small:before {
  content: "\f066";
}
.icon-plus:before {
  content: "\f067";
}
.icon-minus:before {
  content: "\f068";
}
.icon-asterisk:before {
  content: "\f069";
}
.icon-exclamation-sign:before {
  content: "\f06a";
}
.icon-gift:before {
  content: "\f06b";
}
.icon-fire:before {
  content: "\f06d";
}
.icon-eye-open:before {
  content: "\f06e";
}
.icon-eye-close:before {
  content: "\f070";
}
.icon-warning-sign:before {
  content: "\f071";
}
.icon-plane:before {
  content: "\f072";
}
.icon-calendar:before {
  content: "\f073";
}
.icon-random:before {
  content: "\f074";
}
.icon-comment:before {
  content: "\f075";
}
.icon-magnet:before {
  content: "\f076";
}
.icon-chevron-up:before {
  content: "\f077";
}
.icon-chevron-down:before {
  content: "\f078";
}
.icon-retweet:before {
  content: "\f079";
}
.icon-shopping-cart:before {
  content: "\f07a";
}
.icon-folder-close:before {
  content: "\f07b";
}
.icon-folder-open:before {
  content: "\f07c";
}
.icon-resize-vertical:before {
  content: "\f07d";
}
.icon-resize-horizontal:before {
  content: "\f07e";
}
.icon-bar-chart:before {
  content: "\f080";
}
.icon-twitter-sign:before {
  content: "\f081";
}
.icon-facebook-sign:before {
  content: "\f082";
}
.icon-camera-retro:before {
  content: "\f083";
}
.icon-key:before {
  content: "\f084";
}
.icon-cogs:before {
  content: "\f085";
}
.icon-comments:before {
  content: "\f086";
}
.icon-thumbs-up:before {
  content: "\f087";
}
.icon-thumbs-down:before {
  content: "\f088";
}
.icon-star-half:before {
  content: "\f089";
}
.icon-heart-empty:before {
  content: "\f08a";
}
.icon-signout:before {
  content: "\f08b";
}
.icon-linkedin-sign:before {
  content: "\f08c";
}
.icon-pushpin:before {
  content: "\f08d";
}
.icon-external-link:before {
  content: "\f08e";
}
.icon-signin:before {
  content: "\f090";
}
.icon-trophy:before {
  content: "\f091";
}
.icon-github-sign:before {
  content: "\f092";
}
.icon-upload-alt:before {
  content: "\f093";
}
.icon-lemon:before {
  content: "\f094";
}
.icon-phone:before {
  content: "\f095";
}
.icon-check-empty:before {
  content: "\f096";
}
.icon-bookmark-empty:before {
  content: "\f097";
}
.icon-phone-sign:before {
  content: "\f098";
}
.icon-twitter:before {
  content: "\f099";
}
.icon-facebook:before {
  content: "\f09a";
}
.icon-github:before {
  content: "\f09b";
}
.icon-unlock:before {
  content: "\f09c";
}
.icon-credit-card:before {
  content: "\f09d";
}
.icon-rss:before {
  content: "\f09e";
}
.icon-hdd:before {
  content: "\f0a0";
}
.icon-bullhorn:before {
  content: "\f0a1";
}
.icon-bell:before {
  content: "\f0a2";
}
.icon-certificate:before {
  content: "\f0a3";
}
.icon-hand-right:before {
  content: "\f0a4";
}
.icon-hand-left:before {
  content: "\f0a5";
}
.icon-hand-up:before {
  content: "\f0a6";
}
.icon-hand-down:before {
  content: "\f0a7";
}
.icon-circle-arrow-left:before {
  content: "\f0a8";
}
.icon-circle-arrow-right:before {
  content: "\f0a9";
}
.icon-circle-arrow-up:before {
  content: "\f0aa";
}
.icon-circle-arrow-down:before {
  content: "\f0ab";
}
.icon-globe:before {
  content: "\f0ac";
}
.icon-wrench:before {
  content: "\f0ad";
}
.icon-tasks:before {
  content: "\f0ae";
}
.icon-filter:before {
  content: "\f0b0";
}
.icon-briefcase:before {
  content: "\f0b1";
}
.icon-fullscreen:before {
  content: "\f0b2";
}
.icon-group:before {
  content: "\f0c0";
}
.icon-link:before {
  content: "\f0c1";
}
.icon-cloud:before {
  content: "\f0c2";
}
.icon-beaker:before {
  content: "\f0c3";
}
.icon-cut:before {
  content: "\f0c4";
}
.icon-copy:before {
  content: "\f0c5";
}
.icon-paper-clip:before {
  content: "\f0c6";
}
.icon-save:before {
  content: "\f0c7";
}
.icon-sign-blank:before {
  content: "\f0c8";
}
.icon-reorder:before {
  content: "\f0c9";
}
.icon-list-ul:before {
  content: "\f0ca";
}
.icon-list-ol:before {
  content: "\f0cb";
}
.icon-strikethrough:before {
  content: "\f0cc";
}
.icon-underline:before {
  content: "\f0cd";
}
.icon-table:before {
  content: "\f0ce";
}
.icon-magic:before {
  content: "\f0d0";
}
.icon-truck:before {
  content: "\f0d1";
}
.icon-pinterest:before {
  content: "\f0d2";
}
.icon-pinterest-sign:before {
  content: "\f0d3";
}
.icon-google-plus-sign:before {
  content: "\f0d4";
}
.icon-google-plus:before {
  content: "\f0d5";
}
.icon-money:before {
  content: "\f0d6";
}
.icon-caret-down:before {
  content: "\f0d7";
}
.icon-caret-up:before {
  content: "\f0d8";
}
.icon-caret-left:before {
  content: "\f0d9";
}
.icon-caret-right:before {
  content: "\f0da";
}
.icon-columns:before {
  content: "\f0db";
}
.icon-sort:before {
  content: "\f0dc";
}
.icon-sort-down:before {
  content: "\f0dd";
}
.icon-sort-up:before {
  content: "\f0de";
}
.icon-envelope-alt:before {
  content: "\f0e0";
}
.icon-linkedin:before {
  content: "\f0e1";
}
.icon-undo:before {
  content: "\f0e2";
}
.icon-legal:before {
  content: "\f0e3";
}
.icon-dashboard:before {
  content: "\f0e4";
}
.icon-comment-alt:before {
  content: "\f0e5";
}
.icon-comments-alt:before {
  content: "\f0e6";
}
.icon-bolt:before {
  content: "\f0e7";
}
.icon-sitemap:before {
  content: "\f0e8";
}
.icon-umbrella:before {
  content: "\f0e9";
}
.icon-paste:before {
  content: "\f0ea";
}
.icon-user-md:before {
  content: "\f200";
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", Univers, Calibri, "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", Myriad, "DejaVu Sans Condensed", "Liberation Sans", "Nimbus Sans L", Tahoma, Geneva, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#wrapper h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5em;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -6.8em;
  width: 13em;
  padding: 4em 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0.3em solid #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.3em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#wrapper h1 strong {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  display: block;
}
#access {
  zoom: 1;
}
#access:before,
#access:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#access:after {
  clear: both;
}
[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
/* Defaut link style */

#access a,
#access #menu a,
#menu li a {
  background-color: #689384;
  display: block;
  color: #e5f1ea;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5em;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms linear, box-shadow 500ms ease-in, background-color 250ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms linear, box-shadow 500ms ease-in, background-color 250ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 500ms linear, box-shadow 500ms ease-in, background-color 250ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 500ms linear, box-shadow 500ms ease-in, background-color 250ms ease-in;
  transition: transform 500ms linear, box-shadow 500ms ease-in, background-color 250ms ease-in;
}
#access a:hover,
#access #menu a:hover,
#access a.skip-link.focus,
#access #menu a.skip-link.focus,
#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #b9d9ce;
  color: #5a4741;
}
#access {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#access a.skip-link,
#access #menu a.skip-link {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
#access a.skip-link span,
#access #menu a.skip-link span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5em;
  top: 0.5em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 0 0.3em;
}
#access #menu li.active a a,
#access #menu li.active a a:hover,
#access #menu li.active:nth-child(odd) a,
#access #menu li.active:nth-child(odd) a:hover {
  background-color: #5a4741;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}
#active2 {
  background-color: #5a4741;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  content: "\f06c";
}
#menu {
  border: 0 none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu li {
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 500ms linear;
  -moz-transition: max-height 500ms linear;
  -ms-transition: max-height 500ms linear;
  -o-transition: max-height 500ms linear;
  transition: max-height 500ms linear;
}
#menu li a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -moz-binding: url('xml/ellipsis.xml#ellipsis');
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #menu {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: margin 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: margin 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: margin 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: margin 500ms linear;
    transition: margin 500ms linear;
    margin-top: -1.2em;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #menu li {
    max-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    -ms-perspective: 1000px;
    -o-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
  }
  #menu li a {
    -webkit-transform-origin: top 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: top 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: top 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: top 50%;
    transform-origin: top 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) scale(0.97);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) scale(0.97);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg) scale(0.97);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg) scale(0.97);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) scale(0.97);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #48665c;
  }
  #menu li:nth-child(odd) a {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) scale(0.97);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) scale(0.97);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) scale(0.97);
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg) scale(0.97);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) scale(0.97);
  }
  #menu li.active a:before,
  #menu li a:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  #menu li a:hover:before {
    color: #689384;
  }
  #menu li {
    color: #689384;
  }
  #menu li.active a:before,
  #menu li.active a:hover:before {
    color: #fff;
  }
  #menu:target,
  #menu.target {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  #menu:target li,
  #menu.target li {
    max-height: 2.5em;
    height: auto;
  }
  #menu:target li a,
  #menu.target li a {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) scale(1);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0) scale(1);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0) scale(1);
    transform: rotateX(0) scale(1);
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  [class^="icon-"]:before,
  [class*=" icon-"]:before {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #access a.skip-link {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu {
    width: 100%;
    background: #689384;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #menu li {
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    *vertical-align: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #menu li {
    *display: inline;
  }
  #menu li a:before {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease-in;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 500ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 500ms ease-in;
    transition: transform 500ms ease-in;
  }
  #menu li a:hover:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(1em) scale(3) rotate(15deg);
    -moz-transform: translateY(1em) scale(3) rotate(15deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(1em) scale(3) rotate(15deg);
    -o-transform: translateY(1em) scale(3) rotate(15deg);
    transform: translateY(1em) scale(3) rotate(15deg);
  }
}
ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
.dropdown,
.flyout {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown:after {
  font-size: .5em;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.drop-nav,
.flyout-nav {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown:hover > .drop-nav,
.flyout:hover > .flyout-nav {
  display: block;
}
.flyout-nav {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav role="navigation" id="access">
    <a class="skip-link icon-reorder" title="Accéder au menu" href="#menu">Menu</a>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li class="active"><a class="icon-home" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <!-- whitespace
                -->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class='icon-info' href="#">Extra Info </a>
        <ul class="drop-nav">
          <li><a href="Knight Rider.html">Knight Rider</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="The A Team.html">The A Team</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Cheers.html">Cheers</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Highway to Heaven.html">Highway To Heaven</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href='Gilligans Island'>Gilligan's Island</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="icon-envelope-alt" href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: your dropdown menu class `drop-nav li` is set to display inline so you need to change that to display block in your css

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things. first set the selector `drop-nav li` to `display:block` but this is not enough because your `#menu li` selector is overriding this so you need to set a class for the main ul and insert that in your css so your css selector will look like `.something li`

[a working version](http://codepen.io/zeidanbm/pen/EPzNYe?editors=0100)